# rsync backup-dir with files in read-only folders

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync

I am using rsync over ssh to backup directory structure. In that structure there is read-only folder with a few writable folders within. Content in these writable folders does change and needs to be backed up.

The main backup process works fine, but "backup of backup" (`--backup --backup-dir`) fails for folders in read-only folder with:

```
rsync: mkdir failed - permission denied
```

This is `rsync` command:

```
rsync -e "ssh -i some_key_file.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" \
  --backup --backup-dir=backup_dir --force --ignore-errors --delete -a root_folder server:destination_folder/
```

This is folder structure:

```
root_folder
-- read_only_folder
---- writable_folder
```

Rsync fails creating `backup_dir/read_only_folder/writable_folder`.

Because the main part of the backup does work (I assume `rsync` adjusts permission after syncing files), I am thinking that I am just missing something that would apply the same to the `--backup-dir` files.

Comment: I could not find solution for this other than changing adding u+w to the source directory that was read-only and resetting it back with u-w when rsync completes.